# Stability of nonlinear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

What are the conditions of stability  and existence of unique periodic solution  of the simple equation that follows?

$$x''+f(x)=0$$

Comment: I'm thinking if it would be sufficient that $\int_0^x f(\eta)d\eta > 0$